# Swift Fetching smartAlbum with at least one media

Tags: ios, swift, fetch, photosframework

I am fetching all the smartAlbum present in the user library.
The code I am using is this:

```
 var smartAlbums: PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "estimatedAssetCount > 0")
    options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "localizedTitle", ascending: true)]
    smartAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .albumRegular, options: options)
```

The i will display the result in a tableview and I use this to count the number of rows in section:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch Section(rawValue: section)! {
    case .allPhotos: return 1
    case .smartAlbums: return smartAlbums.count
    case .userCollections: return userCollections.count
    }
}
```

Everything works fine... but the fetch result for smartAlbums fetches also album with zero media. Basically it fetches all albums. It seems like the predicate it has not been taken into consideration.
 the same predicate is applied to userCollections and it works fine.

```
 userCollections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .albumRegular, options: options) // this works fine
```

Is there a way to fetch just the smartAlbums with at least one media?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i've solved it:

I've created an extension:

```
extension PHAssetCollection {
var photosCount: Int {
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d OR mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue, PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
    let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: self, options: fetchOptions)
    return result.count
}
```

}

Then in my tableview controller where I'm fetching the objects I've created a an array of subtypes (this to fetch not all the smartAlbums but just the one i needed) and I have initialised an array of type PHCollection an :

```
  let subtypes:[PHAssetCollectionSubtype] = [
    .smartAlbumFavorites,
    .smartAlbumPanoramas,
    .smartAlbumScreenshots,
    .smartAlbumSelfPortraits,
    .smartAlbumVideos,
    .smartAlbumRecentlyAdded,
    .smartAlbumSelfPortraits
]
var smartAlbums: [PHAssetCollection] = []
```

I then created a function to get all the smartAlbums associated with the subtype and with at least a media in it (image or video -> this is executed with the extension previously created):

```
private func fetchSmartCollections(with: PHAssetCollectionType, subtypes: [PHAssetCollectionSubtype]) -> [PHAssetCollection] {
    var collections:[PHAssetCollection] = []
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.includeHiddenAssets = false

    for subtype in subtypes {
        if let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: with, subtype: subtype, options: options).firstObject, collection.photosCount > 0 { // .photosCount comes from extesion
            collections.append(collection)
        }
    }
```

and in vieDidLoad i fetch the objects:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
smartAlbums = fetchSmartCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtypes: subtypes)
}
```

I'm kind of new to swift so I cannot tell if this is the best solution, but it works, and seen that I have not found anything on the net that could help me I thought to share if anybody would need this.